# Skip choosing customer in new order page in admin area

Tags: orders

At the following page:

Sales -> Orders -> Create New Order

I want to skip the page where you choose the customer, so instead it loads the page as if you had clicked a certain customer, and the customer I want it to load is the currently logged in admin.

I'm not sure how to go about this however I am able to retrieve the logged in admin id.

If I take a JavaScript approach, I think I may need to somehow call productGridRowClick(grid, event) on the "order" object.

Or maybe I could load the block directly in PHP, skipping this:

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_customer" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="customer">
    <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_customer_grid" name="grid" />
</block>
```

Comment: Could you explain how you relate the customer to the admin user?

Comment: I am just assuming that an order can be placed for a logged in admin? Is that not the case though?

Comment: No, admin users and customers are in no way related. An admin user has only name, e-mail address, password and a user-role. There is no sales/checkout functionality related to an admin user whereas for a customer it is.

Comment: Oh right I see, thanks for explaining that. I think I got confused, I realise now that it will in fact be for the logged in customer id, not admin id. Sorry!

Comment: But you cannot have customers being logged in into your admin backend...

Comment: There will be an admin account for each customer account that is in a certain customer group. I will fetch the logged in admin ID, then fetch the customer ID for that admin ID, then load the page with that customer ID.

Comment: Interesting stuff, this customer/admin relation. Don't forget to set proper ACLs/permissions :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass selecting a customer screen you will need to create a url in the following format

```
http://www.website.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/start/customer_id/[108]/key/[key]

Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order_create/start", array('customer_id'=> $customer_id));
```

Where `$customer_id` is a valid customer and not a admin user

Take a look at "Create Order" in customer admin

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I was able to override the block and change the method's code. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order::getCreateUrl.